# Question about the return map $R$ of $F_4$ (Logistic map)

Tags: real-analysis, dynamical-systems

I'm current reading "*1.11 - The Schwarzian Derivate*" from "*Introduction to Chaotic Dynamical Systems by Robert L. Devaney*".

Let $J = \left[\frac{1}{4}, \frac{3}{4}\right]$.
In chapter, Devaney defines the return map $R: J- \left \{\frac{1}{2}\right \} \to J$ of $F_4 = 4x (1-x)$ as $R(x) = F^{\phi(x)}_4(x)$ where $\phi(x)$ is the smallest (positive) integer for which $F^{\phi(x)}_4(x) \in J$. My question is about when he proofs that $|R'(x)| > 1$ for each $x \in J$.

First, let $I_k = \left\{x \in \left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{4}\right)| \phi(x) = k\right\}$. In this proof, he says:

> "Since the length of $I_k$ is less than 1/4, it follows that there exists $x_k \in I_k$ with $(F_4^k)'(x_k) > 1$".

Why is this statement true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, for a map on an interval $f \colon I \to \mathbb{R}$ with $|f'(x)| \leq C$ for all $x \in I$ we have
$$ |f(I)| \leq C |I|$$
where $|J|$ is the length of the interval $J$. To see this you may use that
$$ |f(x) - f(y)| \leq C|x-y|, \ \forall \ x,y \in I$$
which follows from the mean value theorem.

Now that we know this, take $C$ a connected component of $I_k$ which is an interval. Notice that $(F_4^k)'$ is never zero on $C$ since a critical point for this map would have to pass by the only critical point of $F_4$ first, that is, $\frac{1}{2}$ and by the minimality of $k$ that doesn't happen. Therefore $F_4^k$ is monotone on $C$ and now we may claim that $F_4^k(C) = J$, otherwise it's a subinterval of $J$, say with endpoints $a<b$ and we will assume without loss of generality that $\frac{3}{4} < a$. In this case, let's extend $C$ a little bit in order to get the image interval with endpoints $a-\epsilon$ and $b$, but $C$ is a connected component of $I_k$ which means either:

1. By extending $C$ we leave $(\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{4})$ which means $a$ in the orbit of $\frac{1}{2}$ or $\frac{3}{4}$, which is impossible either way since these orbits are easy to compute;
2. By extending $C$ we stay in $(\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{4})$ but leave $I_k$, but this extended part is clearly a candidate for $I_k$, unless it's in some $I_j$ for $j<k$, if that's the case there exists $x$ in the boundary of $C$ such that $F_4^k(x) = a$, $F_4^j(x) \in J$ but $F_4^j(C) \cap J = \emptyset$, this would imply that  $F_4^j(x)$ is one of the boundary points of $J$ and so is $a$ since it would be in this orbit, which is impossible.

Therefore, $F_4^k(C) = J$, in particular
$$ \frac{1}{2} =  |F_4^k(C)| > \frac{1}{4} \geq |C|$$
and $|(F_4^k)'|$ cannot be bounded by 1